# query data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

Ok. I've referenced [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560513/query-data-from-multiple-relational-tables) other question which is similar to my situation, I think. but i'll add my situation and what I have tried so far.

```
Ticket Table    
*-------------------------------*
|t_id | repair_id | customer_id |
| 1   |     10    |     11      | 
| 2   |   11,12   |     12      | 
| 3   |   13,14   |     13      |
| 4   |   15,16   |     14      |
*-------------------------------* 
Repair Table    
*-----------------------------------------------------*
|repair_id  | ticket_id | device_type | repair_status | 
|     10    |    1      |   laptop    |     open      |
|     11    |    2      |   tablet    |     open      |
|     12    |    2      |   phone     |     open      | 
|     13    |    3      |   phone     |     open      |
|     14    |    3      |   tablet    |     open      |
|     15    |    4      |   laptop    |     open      |
|     16    |    4      |   laptop    |     open      |
*-----------------------------------------------------*
Customer Table    
*-----------------------------*
|customer_id | f_name | l_name | 
|     11     |  John  | Hughes |  
|     12     |  Julia | Brown  |   
|     13     |  Tim   | Duncan |  
|     14     |  Tony  | Price  |  
*-----------------------------*
```

And I'm wanting the result Table to look as such:

```
Results Table    
*----------------------------------------------------------*
|customer_name | Repair_# | device_type    | repair_status |
| John Hughes  |   10     | laptop         |    open       | 
| Julia Brown  |   11,12  | tablet,phone   |    open       | 
| Tim Duncan   |   13,14  | phone, tablet  |    open       | 
| Tony Price   |   15,16  | laptop, laptop |    open       | 
*----------------------------------------------------------*
```

This is the query that I tried:

```
$query  = "SELECT customers.id, customers.f_name, customers.l_name, device_repairs.repair_id, device_repairs.ticket_id, ";
$query .= "device_repairs.device_type,device_repairs.repair_type, device_repairs.ticket_status, ";
$query .= "FROM tickets ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN customers ON tickets.customer_id = customers.id ORDER BY device_repairs.ticket_id DESC";
```

I know my query isn't right but I'm not quite sure how to setup the INNER JOIN.

**REVISION**

So after some per review. I've added a revised table(s) structure.

```
Ticket Table    
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*
|t_id|repair_id|cust_id|cust_fname|cust_lname|device_type|repair_stat|
| 1  |   10    |  11   |  John    | Hughes   | Laptop    |   open    |
| 2  |   11    |  12   |  Julia   | Brown    | Tablet    |   open    |
| 2  |   12    |  12   |  Julia   | Brown    | Phone     |   open    | 
*--------------------------------------------------------------------* 
Repair Table    
*-----------------------------------------------------*
|repair_id  | ticket_id | device_type | repair_status | 
|     10    |    1      |   laptop    |     open      |
|     11    |    2      |   tablet    |     open      |
|     12    |    2      |   phone     |     open      | 
|     13    |    3      |   phone     |     open      |
|     14    |    3      |   tablet    |     open      |
|     15    |    4      |   laptop    |     open      |
|     16    |    4      |   laptop    |     open      |
*-----------------------------------------------------*
Customer Table    
*-----------------------------*
|customer_id | f_name | l_name | 
|     11     |  John  | Hughes |  
|     12     |  Julia | Brown  |   
|     13     |  Tim   | Duncan |  
|     14     |  Tony  | Price  |  
*-----------------------------*
```

And the *revised* results Table to look as such:

```
Results Table    
*----------------------------------------------------------*
|customer_name | Repair_# | device_type    | repair_status |
| John Hughes  |   10     | laptop         |    open       | 
| Julia Brown  |   11     | tablet         |    open       |
| Julia Brown  |   12  |  | phone          |    open       |  
*----------------------------------------------------------*
```

Hopefully, this is helpful and makes more sense.

I created this query so that the Results Table would output properly. Thanks for all input.

```
$sql = "SELECT customers.id, customers.f_name, customers.l_name, device_repairs.repair_id, device_repairs.device_type, ";
$sql .="device_repairs.repair_type, device_repairs.ticket_status, device_repairs.ticketopen ";
$sql .="FROM customers, device_repairs WHERE customers.id = device_repairs.customer_id ORDER BY device_repairs.ticketopen DESC";
```

Comment: Post what you got out of that query as well. What confuses you about INNER JOIN?

Comment: This is what i get out of the query:Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Comment: OK, you'll probably notice there's around 25 000 questions on SO with that exact error message. Retrieve the error (always check result of your `mysqli_query` function) and post it back.

Answer (score 0):

The ticket table is poorly designed. I wouldn't have two repair IDs put in a single field. The entire idea of having IDs (primary keys ) and foreign keys is lost.

Your tickets table should have 7rows instead of 4 and repair id in that should have only one value. Further the repair_id should be a described as a foreign key and linked to Repair table.

After this you can join customer table to ticket table on customer_id and further join repair table on ticket table.

Comment: Yes. I had initially setup the tables as 2 only (Customers, Repair). However, I ran into the issue of how to distinguish each device as an individual item but still part of 1 ticket. E.g. Customer A brings in 2 devices (Laptop, Tablet). Each will have its own repair "id". I'm trying to track the repair history of each device individually. One device may get repaired sooner than the other and I don't want the "ticket" to close until  both devices are resolved. There is also another part on the front end which you are unaware about.

Comment: Is your query closed Or there is still some further input you need.

Comment: I was able to answer my questuon by adding a column for the customer id in the repair table